# Unable to unzip .zip file on linux machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, zip, tar

I have a large ~10GB zip file that was created using the standard Windows method (right click, select "send to compressed (zipped) folder"). I am able to unzip it just file on my Macbook.

I'm trying to unzip it on an EC2 machine. I know the file is a zip file because when I run `file file.zip` it says:

```
file.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Running `unzip` returns the following error:

```
Archive:  file.zip
warning [file.zip]:  3082769992 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
error [file.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Running `tar xvf file.zip` returns the following:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Archive contains `<{\204\027\333"D\344\210\321o\331' where numeric         off_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `S\354\202},F\3546\276[\265\273' where numeric     time_t value expected
tar: Archive contains ``3c\254\372$:e' where numeric uid_t value expected
tar: Archive contains `\265\306\025+ܫL\352' where numeric gid_t value expected
...etc
```

Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Actually, 7-zip should makes this well, you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Then, you can extract your zip file as follows:

```
7z e file.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried 7-zip and got much farther, though it still failed in the end.

The initial scan of the zip resulted in "ERRORS: Headers Error"

The unzip gets most of the way through (~75%) before saying "ERROR: E_FAIL, Archives with Errors: 1, Open Errors: 1"

I'm expecting about 88,000 files and I end up with ~55k

Comment: Oh! I'm out of space.

Answer (score 3):

I was unable to install 7z on my machine due to no sudo access, but I managed to repair the archive using

`zip -FF archive.zip --out archive_repaired.zip -fz`

and `unzip` worked on the repaired archive.

I found the solution via this [github issue](https://github.com/AmsterdamUMC/AmsterdamUMCdb/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

If your zip archive has 88,000 files and you are dealing with ~10Gig of content, you will need an unzip program that supports the **[zip64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#ZIP64)** extension.

You can check if your unzip program supports **zip64** like this

```
$ unzip -v | grep -i zip64
        ZIP64_SUPPORT (archives using Zip64 for large files supported)
```

If it doesn't have **ZIP64_SUPPORT**, you are out of luck. I suspect your unzip doesn't support **zip64**.

Alternatives are to get a version of unzip that does support **zip64** or use an alternative program, like z-zip.

Answer (score 0):

Your Entire File did not zip most probably and you prematurely moved it. At Least that was the issue with me.

Comment: This should be a comment and not the answer.